# Array of sets in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a graph with some nodes, and I need to assign a set to each node; I want to have something like an array of sets. Is there any way to define such an array?

Comment: What's wrong with using `Set.new` with an array?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of asking us how to do it, you are supposed to try, then when you run into a problem ask about that specific problem. As is, it looks like you might have tried, but we can't tell because there's not any code to review and help debug. We need to see your code, so we can suggest fixes in place, rather than cobble up something totally unrelated, which you then try to shoehorn into place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array of arrays

```
arr=[[],[],[],[],[]]
```

or an array of hashes

```
[x => 1,y => 2, z => 3]
```

Arrays and Hashes are the main way in ruby.

For anyone using actual sets note that you have to

```
require 'set'
```

in IRB to play around with sets

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this to create an array of sets:

```
array = Array.new(3) { |index| Set.new [index] }
=> [#<Set: {0}>, #<Set: {1}>, #<Set: {2}>]
```